# what happen in this script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh

yes_or_no(){

    echo "Is your name $* ?"
    while true 
    do
        echo -n "yes or no"
        read x
        case "$x" in
             y | yes ) return 1;;
             n | no ) return 0;;
            * ) echo "Answer yes or no"
        esac 
    done
    }

if  yes_or_no "$1" 

then

    echo "Hi $1,nice name i"
else

    echo "never mind"
fi

exit 0
```

output-->

```
./fuction1.sh salman khan

Is your name salman ?

yes or non

Hi salman,nice name i
```

why the opposite output cam if i press no then output will be never mind because fuction return 0.
i am totally confuse here can any-buddy help me solve this?

Comment: What you dont understand from above?

Comment: function return 0 when i press no then if condition check and answer will give never mind but it's not like that...why

Comment: If you were using bash, I'd suggest you use `select`

Answer (score 2):

In shell things are not like in other languages. "0" is a code of success:

```
$ true
$ echo $?
0
$ if true ; then echo "True"; fi
True
```

from above you can see for yourself that 0 actually means "0 errors", while anything other than "0" would indicate error code. Thus shell logic is geared towards that rather than C-like where 0 == False and 1 == True

Comment: @salmankhan The preferred way "saying thanks" is by upvoting helpful answers and **accepting** one  (by clicking on the green checkmark) what is best for you.